# Dropdown Menu with jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an error when making a Dropdown Menu with jetpack compose and I don't know how to solve it.

The error is in this code:

```kotlin
list.forEach { label ->
    DropdownMenuItem(
        onClick = {
            selectedItem = label
            expanded = false
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = label)
    }
}
```

I get the following error: `No value passed for parameter 'text'`

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [documentation for DropdownMenuItem](https://www.composables.com/material3/dropdownmenuitem) you'll notice it takes a composable function as the `text` parameter. The text should be defined there instead of the composable body. For example:

```
DropdownMenuItem(
    text = { Text("Label text") },
    onClick = { /* Handle click */ },
    leadingIcon = {
    Icon(
        Icons.Outlined.Edit,
        contentDescription = null
    )
})
```